# Capture the Flag error: could not find or load main class Espresso

Tags: java

Hi there I'm doing a capture the flag event and the current problem is in Java but I don't have any experience working with Java. When I try to run the file I get "could not find or load main class Espresso". I've seen other posts on here and I tried `java -cp . Espresso` but didn't have any luck. I did run `javac Espresso.java` to compile it before running `java Espresso`. Any help would be appreciated here is the code:

```
package com.hackinglab.ctf;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Espresso { public Espresso() {} private static String key = "Stringab";
  private static String cipher = "'>xgx47#)~Fp?8k4%IHsC9_a";

  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString) {
    if (paramArrayOfString.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("You must enter the flag.");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    String str = paramArrayOfString[0];
    System.out.println(str);
    StringBuffer localStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < cipher.length(); i++) {
      localStringBuffer.append((char)(key.charAt(i % key.length()) - cipher.charAt(i) + 55));
    }
    if (localStringBuffer.toString().equals(str)) {
      System.out.println("Flag correct, well done!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Dude, that's wrong!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: give complete path `com.hackinglab.ctf.Espresso`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make sure you have the same folder structure as your package name

> ../com/hackinglab/ctf/Espresso.java

then you can build and run it like

```
javac com/hackinglab/ctf/Espresso.java
java com/hackinglab/ctf/Espresso
```

or remove the line `package com.hackinglab.ctf;` from your source file

Answer (score 1):

The package is part of the class name, and when stored on the disk the package structure is embodied by the folder structure (even in a JAR file, it is still a folder structure). So one "correct" solution would be

```
mkdir bin
javac -d bin Espresso.java
java -cp bin com.hackinglab.ctf.Espresso
```

Note that your source folder should also mirror the package structure (so the compiler can find things when you have more than one class). So the more usual sequence of commands might be something like

```
mkdir bin
mkdir -p "src/com/hackinglab/ctf"
mv Espresso.java src/com/hackinglab/ctf # to place the Espresso.java in the correct folder
javac -d bin -cp src src/com/hackinglab/ctf/Espresso.java
java -cp bin com.hackinglab.ctf.Espresso
```

Giving a directory tree like

```
├── bin
│   └── com
│       └── hackinglab
│           └── ctf
│               └── Espresso.class
└── src
    └── com
        └── hackinglab
            └── ctf
                └── Espresso.java

8 directories, 2 files
```

Then you *might* move on to create a jar file. You'll need a manifest file to [set the application's entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) so that might look like

```
cat <<EOF > src/manifest.txt
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.hackinglab.ctf.Espresso
EOF
cd bin
jar cfm espresso.jar ../src/manifest.txt com/hackinglab/ctf/*.class
```

The tree looks something like

```
├── bin
│   ├── com
│   │   └── hackinglab
│   │       └── ctf
│   │           └── Espresso.class
│   └── espresso.jar
└── src
    ├── com
    │   └── hackinglab
    │       └── ctf
    │           └── Espresso.java
    └── manifest.txt

8 directories, 4 files
```

And in the `bin` folder you can run

```
java -jar espresso.jar
```

Or from any other folder with

```
java -jar /path/to/espresso.jar
```